# Download layers from SoilGrids

Tags: soilgrids

I want to download layers from [SoilGrids](https://soilgrids.org/) using the download data bottom but I get a TIFF file with no data, just a black square of the area. I would like to use some variables to run in Maxent. The area of interest is South America.

Comment: What you are getting is [GeoTIFF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTIFF).

Answer (score 3):

The downloaded file is a GeoTIFF, and when viewed in an image viewer will not render properly. Visible image files are usually three layers of red, green, and blue intensity values but GeoTIFFs are intended for data that might only have one layer, or could have forty-two layers, or more.

To read it you need some GIS software, like open source QGIS or the Python spatial modules or R spatial packages.

Here's a GeoTIFF downloaded from SoilGrids loaded into QGIS with a map background layer. You can see the data values are from 0 to 104.

[image]

If Maxent requires a different format or projection then QGIS can do this and write out most standard GIS raster grid formats. You can also do this with Python code, or R, or most rapidly using the GDAL command-line tools.